# $B^2 = A$ for non diagonalizable $B \in \mathbb{C}^{4x4}$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I have to prove that exist a non diagonalizable matrix $B \in \mathbb{C}^{4x4}$ such that $A = B^{2}$ with 
$
A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 6 & 0 \\
   -1 & -2 & -6 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 4 & 0 \\
   2 & 4 & 12 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
$

My problem is that A is diagonalizable with 
$
D=
  \begin{bmatrix}
   2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
$ and I can't imagine a Jordan matrix B satisfying $A = B^{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: try looking for a block diagonal matrix of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix} X & 0 \\ 0 & Y \end{pmatrix}$$
where $X, Y$ are $2 \times 2$ matrices, and $Y$ is non-zero and nilpotent.

Comment: Thanks Theo!!!!

Comment: No worries!$\hspace{0pt}$